# Handle Network error with Retrofit observable

Tags: android, observable, retrofit, rx-java

When using Observables with Retrofit how do you handle Network failure?

Given this code:

```
Observable<GetJobResponse> observable = api.getApiService().getMyData();
observable
    .doOnNext(new Action1<GetJobResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void call(GetJobResponse getJobResponse) {
            //do stuff with my data
        }
    })
    .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            //do stuff with error message
        }
    });
```

The request just fails without network and onError is not called.  It does not crash, but fails silently. Logs shows Retrofit getting the error:

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api-staging.sittercity.com": No address associated with hostname
     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:29)
```

Using callbacks this is simply passed to the onFailure(RetrofitError error).  How can I get this surfaced with RxJava?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My problem was actually elsewhere in my code.  Handling network errors with rxJava + Retrofit is very easy as it just throws a RetrofitError in the onError method:

```
 @Override
 public void onError(Throwable e) {
     if (e instanceof RetrofitError) {
        if (((RetrofitError) e).isNetworkError()) {
            //handle network error
        } else {
            //handle error message from server
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `.isNetworkError()` is now depreciated. Use `getKind() == Kind.NETWORK.` now. https://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RetrofitError.html But besides that, thanks!

Comment: where should i override `onerror` method in order to catch `RetrofitError`. When I tried to do it in `subscribe()` method Android studio throws `Cannot resolve symbol RetrofitError`

Comment: If using Retrofit 2, it will be a `retrofit.HttpException` instead of `RetrofitError`

Answer (score 13):

This is purely an RxJava issue, not involving that much from Retrofit. `doOnError` is a side-effect, so even though it handles the error, it does not "catch" in the sense of preventing it from bubbling forwards.

You should look at [Error Handling Operators](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators). The most basic option is `onErrorReturn()` which allows you to substitute an error with an item (instance of `GetJobResponse`).

You can put an "error" flag on that item in order to identify it later when you subscribe to the `observable`. Also it's important to know that if you don't subscribe to that observable, it is essentially "dead". You should always subscribe to observables rather than using "doOn___" which are just side-effects (should be used for logging and other non-critical functionality).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll have to play around with this a bit to come up with a solution.

Comment: @André Staltz This saved me from a dark, deep rabbit hole I found myself in after just starting down the Rx path. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you let an observable emit `onError`, all upstream observables will shut down - regardless of whether you "catch" it with `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResumeNext`. Often you don't want that. For example, if your stream starts with a button click that triggers a retrofit request which fails, then the button clicks won't be recognized anymore since the stream terminated.

Use `Observable<Response<Type>>` or `Observable<Result<Type>>` to also handle retrofit errors in `onNext()`.

s. http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/

Answer (score 0):

As of `Retrofit2` and `RxJava2` there is no more `RetrofitError` exception. And its successor `HttpException` only represents HTTP error response codes. Network errors should be handled through `IOException`.

```
 @Override
 public void onError(Throwable e) {
     if (e instanceof IOException) {
            //handle network error
     } else if (e instanceof HttpException) {
            //handle HTTP error response code
     } else {
            //handle other exceptions
     } 
 }
```