# Retrofit Observables and access to Response code in a successfull request

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit and RxJava. I know that i can handle the errors [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25244736/3248593), so i can do things with the corresponding errors.

Now, I have an api call, and i need to get the request code in a `201 Http response code` and do something if `201` occurs and do something else if the response code is `200`. What is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you can use method that returns `Observable<Response>` and `Response` has a method [getStatus()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/client/Response.html#getStatus--) for obtaining response code.
It means you won't get deserialized response and you'd need do perform manual conversion from JSON with [GsonConverter.toBody()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/converter/GsonConverter.html#fromBody-retrofit.mime.TypedInput-java.lang.reflect.Type-) method.